# Connecting MySQL server with Apache Superset using SSH Tunneling

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, apache-superset, tunneling

I am pretty new to Apache Superset and have to connect Superset with our database which is on another server.

The superset Instance has been set and installed on an ec2 instance and the MySQL DB is at a different host. I have been advises to connect the DB server using SSH tunneling.

I have a Tunneling server created and need to use that in Superset. Is there a way how I can achieve that?

Does Superset offer connection via Tunneling? If yes, how can I achieve that?